# Set with getRandom

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, set

This is an interview question: Impement a `Set` class with `get`, `put`, and `getRandom`.

I would consider the following options:

- sorted/unsorted linked list: `get` - O(N), `put` - O(N), `getRandom` - O(N)
- unsorted vector (resizable array): `get` - O(N), `put` - ?, `getRandom` - O(1)
- sorted vector (resizable array): `get` - O(logN), `put` - ?, `getRandom` - O(1)
- hash table: `get` - O(1), `put` - O(1), `getRandom` - O(table size)
- balanced binary search tree: `get` - O(logN), `put` - O(logN), `getRandom` - O(N)

It looks like the best candidates are:

- hash table if `get/put` are much more frequent than `getRandom`
- sorted vector (resizable array) if `getRandom` is much more frequent than `get/put`

Now I wonder if we can combine a vector and hash table somehow to make up a better set.

Comment: In a sorted linked list, lookup and insertion take linear time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make `get`, `put` and `getRandom` all be `O(1)` average time.

What you do is store 2 data structures.  One is a hash.  The other lists the elements in random order in a growable array.

When you `put`, you put it in the hash, add the element to the end of the array, then swap the end of the array for a random array element.

When you `get`, you look in the hash for the element.

When you `getRandom`, you take the last element of the array, and then swap that last element with another spot in the array.

If you want you can add `delete` as just removing the hash.  Now `getRandom` is implemented by taking the element, checking whether it is in the hash, and if it is not then shrinking the array, and repeating.  At this point `getRandom` is occasionally `O(n)` **BUT** the amortized average costs of all operations can be proven to be `O(1)`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to: store the elements in the array in insertion order, store the index in the array with the key in the hash table, implement `getRandom` by generating a random index into the array, and implement `delete` as deletion in a hash table + O(1) deletion from the array using the index that was stored in the array earlier? +1, btw.

Comment: @larsmans, how would you have O(1) deletion from an array? @btilly, I think your random method will be slightly skewed with subsequent deletions (i.e. `put(x); delete(x); put(x)`).

Comment: @btilly Also, I don't see how could this be amortized `O(1)`. Suppose you add n different items, then proceed to delete those n items and ask for a random element. You would do `2n + 1` operations in `O(n²)` time, making overall amortized cost `O(n)`. Of course, it`s my fault not to notice the original problem had no deletions -- this answers the question perfectly as asked, for that +1.

Comment: @ffao: easy. To delete element i, swap it with the last element and decrement the size so that the last one "falls off". Then, look up the last element in the hash table and change the index there.

Comment: @ffao There is skew if the same element is inserted/deleted, good catch.  To avoid that you could tag each inserted element with a unique identifier, so that if you insert the same element later you can tell them apart.  As for O(1) amortized, consider the cost of removing the element when you later encounter it as part of the cost of the delete that did not actually find and clear it.  I have no idea why you think that those `2n+1` operations would be `O(n^2)`.  Hash inserts and deletes are `O(1)`, and pushing/popping from an array is amortized `O(1)` as well.

Comment: @larsmans that is a good strategy.  However it is slower than the one that I gave.  For instance on your delete you have to delete the hash, then find and swap, then update the hash so that it knows where the moved element is.  So you had 2 hash lookups to do.  My approach only had to do 1 hash lookup, and then later might have to pull an element off of the end.  Other than that I'm doing a swap on every insert you are on on every delete.  I assume that a swap (which is just swapping pointers) is very fast.

Comment: @btilly I thought it was O(n²) because I thought popping from an array was O(n), larsmans cleared that up for me already.

Comment: @btilly: that's true. I guess there's a tradeoff between the speeds of the various operations here.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep a separate structure that tells you how many items there are in each bucket of a hash table, you can use binary search to find the n-th element, which would give you O(log n) for all three operations.

A balanced binary search tree augmented with a "count" for each node (that tells how many nodes has the subtree rooted at this node) would work as well for those bounds.

Some corrections to the above: you can't do random access in a linked list, so all operations are O(N). Also, put is O(n) in both vectors due to having to displace elements in the sorted version and checking for duplicates in the unsorted version.

Answer (score 0):

find ~O(1)
delete ~O(1)
add ~O(1) 
For Random we use an array with all the elements and select a random element O(1)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#define MOD 666013
using namespace std;

int N;
vector<int> G[MOD];

vector<int>::iterator find(int x)
{
    int list=x%MOD;                  // f(i) = i % MOD this is my hash function
    vector<int>::iterator it;

    for (it=G[list].begin();it!=G[list].end();++it)
        if (*it==x)
            return it;
    return G[list].end();
}

void add(int x)
{
    int list=x%MOD;                     //again this is my hash function that gives me the key
    if (find(x)==G[list].end())
        G[list].push_back(x);
}

void delete(int x)
{
    int list=x%MOD;
    vector<int>::iterator it=find(x);

    if (it!=G[list].end())
        G[list].erase(it);
}
```

Comment: It would be pretty easy to just search/replace those few words, and rather convenient for those who don't speak Romanian.

Comment: I'm baffled by the phrase "random is also O(1) if you know what are you looking [for]". Care to explain?

Comment: Find is O(1) so it all depends of your random function, if your random function gives an element in constant time than "Random an element" is O(1)

Comment: You mean, generate a random hash value and look that up? That wouldn't work with a chained hash table, and in one that overallocates, you might find a bucket with no value in it.

Comment: I'm not saying that ... I'm just saying it depends on how you write your random function( and to create a random hash value is not what i am suggesting ). Depends on how you manage your date, you cad save an array of your elements and just random an element of that array O(1), in the end it depends on how you manage the random function. And @ffao that is funny and offensive.

Comment: @larsmans I am intrigued by the fact that for my solution you suggested a "funny random algorithm" ( that was obvious a bad one) when i was just saying that depends on how you create the random algorithm; and not suggesting what you where saying ; and there (in btilly post) you suggested another random function( like the random i suggested ).